# Bootstrap table with scroll bar when screen size is small

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollbar, bootstrap-table

I have a bootstrap table with 8 columns and several rows and I would like to show this table with scroll bar when the size of screen is reduced because otherwise tha table get off the wrapper layout. The problem is that the scroll bar is ever show and whereas it is quite ugly I would like to show only when it is necessary, how can I do it?
Is it better to use jQuery plugin like this [table collapse](http://themergency.com/footable/)

```
<div class="panel-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"
                    id="fleetsTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Application</th>
                            <th>Cubic</th>
                            <th>Power</th>
                            <th>Euro class</th>
                            <th>Engine Type</th>
                            <th>Traction</th>
                            <th>Transmission</th>
                            <th>Cars</th>
                            <th>Add Car</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr th:each="fleet : ${fleets}" class="odd gradeX">
                            <td class="col-xs-2" th:text="${fleet.application}"></td>
                            <td class="col-xs-1" th:text="${fleet.cubic}"></td>
                            <td class="col-xs-1" th:text="${fleet.power}"></td>
                            <td class="col-xs-1" th:text="${fleet.euroClass}"></td>
                            <td class="col-xs-1" th:text="${fleet.engineType}"></td>
                            <td class="col-xs-2" th:text="${fleet.traction}"></td>
                            <td class="col-xs-2" th:text="${fleet.transmission}"></td>
                            <td class="col-xs-1"><button id="showCarsButton"
                                    type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Show cars</button></td>
                            <td class="col-xs-1"><button id="addCarButton"
                                    type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add car</button></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.panel-body -->
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this 
    table style="overflow:auto"